# How to deploy pocketbase to an already running apache2 site?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, linode, pocketbase

I want to add a backend to my website and I have decided that I want to use Pocketbase!
I have tried many things but nothing really worked.

I would love to describe what I've tried so far but to be honest I don't even unterstand myself what I did. I have already created the pb directory with the executable. Im using a linode server running on ubuntu. How would I make Pocketbase work so when I go to omikron.me you see my website but going to omikron.me/_/ would go to the admin panel?